# Boinc won't connect to the client

Tags: boinc

I tried to use my computer to distributed computing projects World Community Grid/Outsmart Ebola Together and World Community Grid/FightAIDS@Home. It worked nicely but yesterday the *Boinc* started to say just:

```
Not connected to a client.
```

Does anyone has some ideas why it says so? Now it looks like I have no tasks to do and I'm not part in any research project. And it seems to be impossible to attach  any projects as the menu `Add project or account manager...` just closes the drop-down menu. Is this a bug or is there some setup I need to check?

The version is 7.2.42 (x64) and wxWidgets version 2.8.12.

Comment: Where is it saying  "Not connected to a client"  Are you using the manager?  Have you tried to connect to a project?  If so, which one and by what means?

Comment: I'm using the manager. I have LXDE desktop and when I move the mouse above the boinc-logo in a Panel, the pop-up has the text. When I tried to connect a project, there is no a window where I can select the project.

Comment: And have you tried connecting the client to a project yet?

Comment: I tried but the menu `add project or account manager ...` won't do anything except it closes the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reproducing your error, I was able to get it running by following the general linux start instructions [here.](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Stop_or_start_BOINC_daemon_after_boot)

First, kill all boinc processes including the manager:

```
sudo killall boinc
killall boincmgr
```

Then start the daemon:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/boinc-client start
```

Fire up your manager again and give it a shot.

I also found a system restart can provide roughly the same effect.

Let me know if this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. boinc-client and boincmgr were running nicely for months, and then one day I noticed that my list of Tasks was gone, so I checked the Projects tab and they were gone too, and then I noticed the "Not connected to a client" icon at the bottom of the screen.

I have uninstalled boinc-client and boincmgr, restarted the computer, reinstalled, no change. I'm not able to add my projects.

I then tried:

```
sudo killall boinc

killall boincmgr

sudo /etc/init.d/boinc-client start
```

No change.